# How to get source code of a class constructor in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'd like to get source code of class constructor.

For normal functions, `toString()` can show source code of itself. But constructor's toString() shows the entire class' source code.

I have a demo here:

```js
class TestClass {
  constructor() {
    console.log('constructor');
  }

  hello() {
    console.log('hello');
  }
}

console.log(' ----- hello -----')
console.log(TestClass.prototype.hello.toString())
console.log(' ----- constructor -----')
console.log(TestClass.prototype.constructor.toString())
```

Comment: I am not sure I can answer your question, but I would just point out that this seems spec dependent. For instance, using tsc to process the file, with target es5 I get the behavior you seek and with target es6 I get the behavior you observe.